# How store items of a dictionary to another dictionary with a key in swift?

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift, dictionary

I got a dictionary say `dict1` with some keys and values and i want to store all the values of `dict1` to another dictionary say `dict2` with a key and i tried  parse them to JSON using `SwiftyJson`.
What i tried has been given below,

```
var dict1 = [String: String]()
var dict2 = [String: String]()

// Values of dict1
dict1["details"] = "XXXXX"

//trying to save values of dict1 to dict2
dict2["moreDetails"] = dict1 as? String
let jsonValue = JSON(dict2)
print(jsonValue)
```

What i obtain is an empty jsonString like this `{    }`

What i actually want to get is

```
{
"moreDetails" :{
         "details" : "XXXXX"
      }
}
```

How could i achieve the above

Comment: try this :- `var Dict2 = [String: Any]()`

Answer (score 0):

As AshvinGudaliya's comment suggests, the issue is the type of `dict2` - you've typed it as `[String: String]`, and then you try to put an object of type `[String: String]` as a value - but it will only accept `String` values.

Creating `dict2` as a `[String: Any]` will allow you to add a non-string value to it, in this case the contents of `dict1`, a `[String: String]`